# Invalid covariant return type on overridden methods with reference return types

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing inheritence with PIMPL idiom. I have two classes such as :

```cpp
// In Base.h
class Base
{
  virtual BaseImpl& getImpl() const;
private:
  std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> _pImpl;
};

// In Derived.h
class Derived : public Base
{
  DerivedImpl& getImpl() const /* override */;
};

// In BaseImpl.h
class BaseImpl { ... };

// In DerivedImpl.h
class DerivedImpl : public BaseImpl { ... };
```

Now if I uncomment the `override` keyword above, compiler complains that the covariant return type is invalid while overriding `getImpl()`.

Since `DerivedImpl` derives from `BaseImpl` and I return references, where is the issue with covariance here?

**NOTE** : This code sample is voluntarily not sorted, classes are in independent files. The issue is only about `override` keyword. Code compiles without it.

Comment: Did you mean to reorder the declarations (or have forward declarations)? As it stands, this code cannot compile because `BaseImpl` and `DerivedImpl` are used before they are declared.

Comment: Did you forget `virtual` in the `Base` class's function declaration?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Zv2GVr). Please create a [mcve] (which will require the code to not be intentionally unsorted).

Comment: @MaxLanghof It is irrelevant as my code compiles without override keywords

Comment: @ChrisMM Sorry, I forgot it in my code sample but not in my actual code

Comment: Works fine. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/jXfc7y Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @A.Gille It also compiles if you delete all your code. Point being that "it compiles" need not mean "it does what you want". But the behavior you see is indeed strange - whether you add `override` or not shouldn't change whether that error is produced. Can you add the compiler and version you are using?

Comment: My guess would be, you only forward-declared `BaseImpl` and `DerivedImpl` before defining `Base` and `Derived`. So the compiler is not aware that `DerivedImpl` is in fact derived from `BaseImpl`. As far as it can tell, these are two unrelated classes, and therefore not covariant.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right. Since I don't want my implementation headers to be linked in interface headers to avoid delivering them, I have to forward declare them instead...

Comment: Purpose of pimpl is to hide the class definition from interface... why have `virtual` method returning it?

Comment: @Jarod42 Since `pImpl` is stored in `Base`, derived classes need to implement a method down-casting this pointer to their type. Calling `getImpl()` from base class must return `pImpl` while calling it from derived class must return a cast of it. Maybe not the best/cleanest solution. Would appreciate better solution if any

Comment: @A.Gille: Maybe just a naming issue, but `virtual BaseImpl& getImpl() const;` seems wrong. `virtual IService& getMyService() const = 0;` would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since DerivedImpl derives from BaseImpl and I return references, where is the issue with covariance here?

The issue is that the compiler cannot predict whether `DerivedImpl` would derive from `BaseImpl` or not. It doesn't yet know that because `DerivedImpl` isn't yet defined at the point where the overridden function was declared. This could be solved by re-ordering the definitions:

```
class BaseImpl {  };
class DerivedImpl : public BaseImpl {  };

class Derived : public Base
{
  DerivedImpl& getImpl() const override ;
};
```

If you cannot make the definition of the return type visible at the point of the declaration of the function, then you cannot use covariant return type.

Comment: I think your last sentence is the root cause of my issue